# Rails 3 with mysql and omniauth => [BUG] Segmentation fault

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I try to run the project together with **omniauth (devise + omniauth) and mysql**.

For example Twitter authorization gives an error:

> /Users/n3mfis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:784:
>   [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 1.9.3dev
>   (2011-05-18 trunk 31628)
>   [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]
>
> -- Control frame information ----------------------------------------------- c:0054 p:---- s:0330 b:0330 l:000329
>   d:000329 CFUNC  :connect c:0053 p:0011
>   s:0327 b:0327 l:000a80 d:000326 BLOCK 
>   /Users/n3mfis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:784
>   c:0052 p:0111 s:0325 b:0325 l:0024a0
>   d:0024a0 METHOD
>   /Users/n3mfis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:60
>   c:0051 p:0026 s:0313 b:0313 l:000312
>   d:000312 METHOD
>   /Users/n3mfis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:91
>
> ....
>
> 1069
>   /Users/n3mfis/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/bundler/gems/rails-505defc27ead/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb
>   1070
>   /Users/n3mfis/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/bundler/gems/rails-505defc27ead/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb
>   1071
>   /Users/n3mfis/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/multi_json-1.0.2/lib/multi_json/engines/json_gem.rb  1072
>   /Users/n3mfis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.7.0/enc/trans/utf_16_32.bundle
>
> [NOTE] You may have encountered a bug
>   in the Ruby interpreter or extension
>   libraries. Bug reports are welcome.
>   For details:
>   http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
>
> Abort trap

If I change mysql to sqlite, then everything works fine...

For mysql and sqlite other features of the site work fine without any errors (scaffold)

I tried

- ruby ruby-1.9.2-p180 and last version ruby 1.9.3dev
- rails 3.0.7 and rails 3.1.0beta1

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this option:
`export RUBYOPT='-r openssl'`